# How to check R error logs?

Tags: php, mysql, r

I am integrating r with Php but when I executed R under Phpscript than it takes some time and stop running, So I want to know that the error is because od r or any other reason So please tell me how to check R error logs?

Comment: It will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel

Comment: this may be caused by the php script max execution time, set it in the php.ini